# Having certificate issue when validating my app

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

I had been pushing internal testing versions for the last few weeks ok and it's been smooth until late last week when I ran into something odd in Xcode when I try to validate my app.

I have it set to manually sign my app and it shows my certificates in there ok but when I start to validate my app I see [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJYxc.png) that asks for me to select my certificate and profile. However, there is no profile to select.

Am hoping someone sees this and knows what it is. I'm new to all of this so am a bit lost at the moment as to the cause of this. I've cleaned the build folder and checked to make sure there is a certificate there but something is missing.

Comment: You need to be in the Apple Developer Program

Comment: I am. As I mentioned above, I've been pushing versions previously.

Comment: Try contacting apple, the problem could be with Apple ID